# How many hotdogs did each male guest eat?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

Nina cooked 121 hotdogs for the Christmas party. There were 16 male and 18 female guests. Each male guest ate 1 more hotdog than each female guest. Each of the female guests, including Nina, ate equal number of hotdogs. How many hotdogs did each male guest eat?

Comment: The wording could be improved since Nina is not a guest.

Comment: I really have no idea, can you at least give me a hint? @N.F.Taussig?

Comment: Let $x$ be the number of hotdogs each male guest ate. Now work out all the relevant numbers in terms of $x$, get an equation, and solve it.

Comment: I guess I wasn't counted, since I ate one less of hotdogs than Nina did.

Comment: That's an alternative fact, btw.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x$ be the number of hotdogs that one female guest ate . Then we have :

$$16(x+1)+18x+x=121$$
$$16x +16+19x=121$$
$$35x=121-16$$
$$35x=105$$
$$x=3$$

So number of hotdogs that each male guest ate is $4$ .

Answer (score 2):

Let each female eat x hotdogs.

We have 19 females including Nina.

So hotdogs eaten by females = 19x

Each male eat 1 more hotdog than by female. So hotdog eaten by each male = (x + 1)

And we have 16 male so total hotdogs eaten by them = 16(x + 1)

Total hotdogs eaten by male and female = 121

19x + 16(x + 1) = 121

19x + 16x + 16 = 121

35x = 121 - 16

35x = 105

x = 3

So each female eat 3 hotdogs.

And each male eat 4 hotdogs.

Comment: Any doubt you can ask.

Answer (score 1):

Assume all hotdogs are eaten, i.e. number of hotdogs eaten is $121$.

If each of $16$ male guests did not eat the $1$ hotdog more than each of the female guests,

- the total number of hotdogs eaten would have been $121-16=105$
- all guests (including Nina) would have eaten the same number of hotdogs each which is $105\div 35=3$

However, since each male guest ate $1$ more, the number of hotdogs eaten by each male guest is $\color{red}4$.